# How to add to the layout compound component programmatically Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, view, custom-component

I created a compound  component `Box` which I want to add to the layout. `Box` xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutForBlock"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:background="@drawable/screen_background" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonContent"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/beach_bed" android:background="@drawable/buttonbackground" android:clickable="true" android:layout_margin="5dp" android:contentDescription="@string/sample_text"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewContent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/sample_text"
            android:textColor="@color/deep_blue" android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</merge>
```

`Box` class:

```
public class Box extends LinearLayout  {

    private TextView textContent;
    private ImageView imageContent;

    public Box(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        ((Activity)getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.box, this);
        setupViewItems();
    }

    private void setupViewItems() {
        textContent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewContent);
        imageContent = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonContent);
    }

    public void setTextContent(String text) {
        this.textContent.setText(text);
    }
    public void setImageContent(String tag) {
        this.imageContent.setContentDescription(tag);
    }
}
```

Everything works if I add the `Box` to the main xml file like:

```
<com.mypackage.alexey.Box
android:id="@+id/mybox"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
/>
```

The problem is that I'd like to create many of boxes programmatically something like this: `Box mybox= new Box();`. How to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would suggest you also implement the constructors of the `LinearLayout` that takes only a `Context`:

```
public Box(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
```

Then in your `Activity`, when you want to add a new `Box`, instantiate the `Box` class and add it to your layout:

```
// I assumed you have a LinearLayout to which you want to add your Box
LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent_id);
//create the Box and added to the parent above
Box theBox = new Box(this); // if you are in an Activity
//some LayoutParams to replicate your xml attributes
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
// set the Orientation for the Box
theBox.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
//add the Box
parent.addView(theBox);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but there is a problem when I try to assign the value: theBox.setTextContent("New content"); i get exception(NullPointerException)

Comment: @alexey As you instantiate the `Box` class and `theBox` is a valid object that means the `NullPointerException` probably comes from `textContent` being `null`(it isn't found in the layout). I don't know how the call to `onFinishInflate` is made(but I suspect it works for the xml layout),I would suggest you to move the code where you inflate the `R.layout.box` file and setup the views(`setupViewItems()`) in the constructor that takes a simple `Context` and try again. Also use this version of `inflate`: `inflate(R.layout.box, this, true);`